# Limit labels number on Chart.js line chart

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, charts, chart.js

I want to display all of the points on my chart from the data I get, but I don't want to display all the labels for them, because then the chart is not very readable. I was looking for it in the docs, but couldn't find any parameter that would limit this.

I don't want to take only three labels for example, because then the chart is also limited to three points. Is it possible?

I have something like that right now:

[image]

If I could just leave every third-fourth label, it would be great. But I found absolutely nothing about labels options.

Comment: can you provide link?

Comment: to website? nope, I'm doing app on android and this chart is on my local page..

Comment: Please specify which library do you use, ChartJS by DevExpress or Chart.js?

Comment: @mmmm did you figure something out? I tried Nikita's answer below but it left me with this strange gap: https://jsfiddle.net/askhflajsf/xzk6sh1q/

Comment: Nikita's answer seem to be the correct one. @mmmm, please consider marking it as the correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39326127/179138

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Try adding the [`options.scales.xAxes.ticks.maxTicksLimit`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-linear-scale) option:

```
xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    ticks: {
        autoSkip: true,
        maxTicksLimit: 20
    }
}]
```

Comment: The answer above plus this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37257056/558094, is the bomb.

Comment: @Nikita your solution is working but when i set chart have maxTicksLimit 7 but  load chart and chart data length 8 then it will display maxTicksLimit 8. have you idea please suggest me  ? thanks

Comment: Something is wrong here. I'm getting a huge gap between the last two ticks: https://jsfiddle.net/askhflajsf/xzk6sh1q/

Comment: The link to the docs does not work anymore. Couldn't find this information in the docs at all but it works :)

Comment: Where do you get this info from? A lot of unswers i'm reading for Chart.js - i'm unable to find in their docs http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/ , am i missing some place where i may actually find all those little properties and overridable callbacks documented?

Comment: You can also add `maxRotation: 0` if you want it not to rotate before start dropping the labels.

Answer (score 24):

For concreteness, let's say your original list of labels looks like:

`["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]`

If you only want to display every 4th label, filter your list of labels so that every 4th label is filled in, and all others are the empty string (e.g. `["0", "", "", "", "4", "", "", "", "8"]`).

Comment: This is a great hack, thanks! I added it [here](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/12).

Comment: Mind that passing `""` also removes corresponding tooltips on the graph!

Comment: Unless I am wrong this can be easily done with a list comprehension if you want e.g. to show every 10th label:     `my_labels = [my_labels[i] if i % 10 == 0 else "" for i in range(len(my_list))]`. The number 10 can of course be declared as a constant at the beginning of the file for easier parameterization of the process.

Comment: it also could be done without **`""`**, as in the answer to this question [vertical gird line issue with chart.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39135489/vertical-gird-line-issue-with-chart-js) where the OP had an issue with black line appears on the first occurrence of this double quote, in such case it helped, again as @haywire mentioned it removes the label from the tooltip

Answer (score 19):

For anyone looking to achieve this on Chart JS V2 the following will work:

```
 var options =  {  
         scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                afterTickToLabelConversion: function(data){


                    var xLabels = data.ticks;

                    xLabels.forEach(function (labels, i) {
                        if (i % 2 == 1){
                            xLabels[i] = '';
                        }
                    });
                } 
            }]   
        }
}
```

Then pass the options variable as usual into a:

```
myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: options
});`
```

Answer (score 17):

**UPDATE:**

I'v updated my fork with the latest pull (as of Jan 27, 2014) from NNick's Chart.js master branch. 
https://github.com/hay-wire/Chart.js/tree/showXLabels

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

For those still facing this issue, I forked Chart.js a while back to solve the same problem. You can check it out on: 
https://github.com/hay-wire/Chart.js/tree/skip-xlabels => Older branch! Check showXLabels branch for latest pull.

**How to use:**

Applicable to bar chart and line chart.

User can now pass a `{ showXLabels: 10 }` to display only 10 labels (actual displayed labels count might be a bit different depending on the number of total labels present on x axis, but it will still remain close to 10 however)

Helps a lot when there is a very large amount of data. Earlier, the graph used to look devastated due to x axis labels drawn over each other in the cramped space. With `showXLabels`, user now has the control to reduce the number of labels to whatever number of labels fit good into the space available to him.

See the attached images for a comparison.

Without `showXLabels` option:
[image]

With `{ showXLabels: 10 }` passed into option:
[image]

Here's some discussion on it:
https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/pull/521#issuecomment-60469304

Comment: Would love to use this but I must be doing something wrong.  I referenced https://github.com/hay-wire/Chart.js/blob/showXLabels/Chart.js but (as of Oct 30, 2015) it doesn't work and doesn't even contain the phrase "showXLabels".  The older one, at https://github.com/hay-wire/Chart.js/blob/skip-xlabels/Chart.js, works just fine.  Would love to get a working, tagged version of the latest so I can safely CDN-link it from RawGit.  This Fiddle (while not distilled to just the issue) shows what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/45cLcxdh/14/

Comment: Tried using this but it looks like 'Chart.Line.js' doesn't get used, thus nothing changes. I used "new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);" to create a chart.

Comment: Using Chart JS 2.6.0 and the option does not work. Eventually I had to use @ben's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26183983/3319454

Comment: I think this is part of a previous version

Comment: @alexalejandroem Yes it was answered in 2014! ;-)

Answer (score 15):

In Chart.js 3.2.0:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        x: {
            ticks: {
                maxTicksLimit: 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

For Chart.js 3.3.2, you can use @Nikita Ag's approach with a few changes. You can check the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.3.2/axes/cartesian/linear.html#linear-axis-specific-tick-options). Put `ticks` in `xAxis` in `scales`. Example:

```
...
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxis: {
            ticks: {
                maxTicksLimit: 10
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 9):

for axis rotation

use this:

```
          scales: {
        xAxes: [
          {
            // aqui controlas la cantidad de elementos en el eje horizontal con autoSkip
            ticks: {
              autoSkip: true,
              maxRotation: 0,
              minRotation: 0
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

i had a similar type of issue, and was given a nice solution to my specific issue [show label in tooltip but not in x axis for chartjs line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604040/show-label-in-tooltip-but-not-in-x-axis-for-chartjs-line-chart). See if this helps you

Answer (score 2):

According to the [chart.js github issue #12](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/12). Current solutions include:

1. Use 2.0 alpha (not production)
2. Hide x-axis at all when it becames too crowd (cannot accept at all)
3. manually control label skip of x-axis (not in responsive page)

However, after a few minutes, I thinks there's a better solution.

The following snippet will hide labels **automatically**. By modify `xLabels` with empty string before invoke `draw()` and restore them after then. Even more, re-rotating x labels can be applied as there's more space after hiding.

```
var axisFixedDrawFn = function() {
    var self = this
    var widthPerXLabel = (self.width - self.xScalePaddingLeft - self.xScalePaddingRight) / self.xLabels.length
    var xLabelPerFontSize = self.fontSize / widthPerXLabel
    var xLabelStep = Math.ceil(xLabelPerFontSize)
    var xLabelRotationOld = null
    var xLabelsOld = null
    if (xLabelStep > 1) {
        var widthPerSkipedXLabel = (self.width - self.xScalePaddingLeft - self.xScalePaddingRight) / (self.xLabels.length / xLabelStep)
        xLabelRotationOld = self.xLabelRotation
        xLabelsOld = clone(self.xLabels)
        self.xLabelRotation = Math.asin(self.fontSize / widthPerSkipedXLabel) / Math.PI * 180
        for (var i = 0; i < self.xLabels.length; ++i) {
            if (i % xLabelStep != 0) {
                self.xLabels[i] = ''
            }
        }
    }
    Chart.Scale.prototype.draw.apply(self, arguments);
    if (xLabelRotationOld != null) {
        self.xLabelRotation = xLabelRotationOld
    }
    if (xLabelsOld != null) {
        self.xLabels = xLabelsOld
    }
};

Chart.types.Bar.extend({
    name : "AxisFixedBar",
    initialize : function(data) {
        Chart.types.Bar.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        this.scale.draw = axisFixedDrawFn;
    }
});

Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name : "AxisFixedLine",
    initialize : function(data) {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        this.scale.draw = axisFixedDrawFn;
    }
});
```

Please notice that `clone` is an external dependency.

Answer (score 2):

you can limit at as

```
scales: {
                x: {
                  ticks: {
                    // For a category axis, the val is the index so the lookup via getLabelForValue is needed
                    callback: function(val, index) {
                    // Hide the label of every 2nd dataset
                    return index % 5 === 0 ? this.getLabelForValue(val) : '';
                    },
                  }
                }
              }
```

this will skip 4 labels and set the 5th one only.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To set a custom number of ticks regardless of your chartsjs version:

```
yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
        stepSize: Math.round((Math.max.apply(Math, myListOfyValues) / 10)/5)*5,
        beginAtZero: true,
        precision: 0
    }
}]
```

**10 = the number of ticks**

**5 = rounds tick values to the nearest 5. All your y values will have the same step size.**

Similar will work for xAxes too.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following code:

```
xAxes: [{
    ticks: {
        autoSkip: true,
        maxRotation: 90
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may well not need anything with this new built-in feature.

A built-in label auto-skip feature detects would-be overlapping ticks and labels and removes every nth label to keep things displaying normally. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/

Answer (score -1):

[This answer](//stackoverflow.com/questions/22064577/limit-labels-number-on-chartjs-line-chart#32569127) works like a charm.

If you are wondering about the `clone` function, try this one:

```
var clone = function(el){ return el.slice(0); }
```

Answer (score -2):

In the Chart.js file, you should find (on line 884 for me)

```
var Line = function(...
    ...
    function drawScale(){
        ...
        ctx.fillText(data.labels[i], 0,0);
        ...
```

If you just wrap that one line call to `fillText` with  `if ( i % config.xFreq === 0){ ... }`
and then in `chart.Line.defaults` add something line `xFreq : 1` you should be able to start using `xFreq` in your `options` when you call `new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options)`.

Mind you this is pretty hacky.

Comment: never change the original library file, which will break after a version update.