# Skip x labels on line chart

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

I need to make a chart with data from 1 full year, but it has too many x labels.

I did this to remove some:

```
var labels= []

for(var i = 0; i< 360;i++) {
  labels.push(i%30 == 0 ? "":i);
}
```

This worked fine for a while, but now I need the `tooltip` to show the exact day so I need the label for that.

I'm using `angularJs` and `ChartJs`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show label in tooltip but not in x axis for chartjs line chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604040/show-label-in-tooltip-but-not-in-x-axis-for-chartjs-line-chart)

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't specify `autoSkip: false` for ticks of x-axes, you should have x-axes labels auto skipped. It is by default true. So you shouldn't have overwhelming labels, plus tooltips should still show those auto skipped data.

```
 xAxes: [{
     ticks: {
         autoSkip: false,
         fontSize: 11,
         ...
     }
 }]
```