# How can I evenly distribute ticks when using maxTicksLimit?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I made a line chart using Chart.js version 2.1.3.

```
        var canvas = $('#gold_chart').get(0);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var fillPatternGold = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canvas.height);
        fillPatternGold.addColorStop(0, '#fdca55');
        fillPatternGold.addColorStop(1, '#ffffff');

        var goldChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            animation: false,
            data: {
                labels: dates,
                datasets: [{
                    label: '',
                    data: prices,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: '#a97f35',
                    backgroundColor: fillPatternGold
                }]
            },
            title: {
                position: 'bottom',
                text: '\u7F8E\u5143 / \u76CE\u53F8'
            },
            options: {
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                tooltips: {
                    callback: function(tooltipItem) {
                        return tooltipItem.yLabel;
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            maxTicksLimit: 8
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
```

The output is as follow:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, I limited the maximum count of ticks to 8 via `maxTicksLimit`. However, the distribution is not even. How can I make the ticks distribute evenly?

p.s. there are always 289 records in the dataset, and the data is recorded every 5 minutes. Sample values of `prices` variable are:

```
[
  {"14:10", 1280.3},
  {"14:15", 1280.25},
  {"14:20", 1282.85}
]
```

I tried different values of `maxTicksLimit`, and the results are still not distributed evenly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Chart.js uses an integral `skipRatio` (to figure out how many labels to skip). With Chart.js v2.1.x, you can write your own plugin to use a fractional skipRatio

---

**Preview**

[image]

---

**Script**

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    afterUpdate: function (chart) {
        var xScale = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
        if (xScale.options.ticks.maxTicksLimit) {
            // store the original maxTicksLimit
            xScale.options.ticks._maxTicksLimit = xScale.options.ticks.maxTicksLimit;
            // let chart.js draw the first and last label
            xScale.options.ticks.maxTicksLimit = (xScale.ticks.length % xScale.options.ticks._maxTicksLimit === 0) ? 1 : 2;

            var originalXScaleDraw = xScale.draw
            xScale.draw = function () {
                originalXScaleDraw.apply(this, arguments);

                var xScale = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
                if (xScale.options.ticks.maxTicksLimit) {
                    var helpers = Chart.helpers;

                    var tickFontColor = helpers.getValueOrDefault(xScale.options.ticks.fontColor, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor);
                    var tickFontSize = helpers.getValueOrDefault(xScale.options.ticks.fontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize);
                    var tickFontStyle = helpers.getValueOrDefault(xScale.options.ticks.fontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle);
                    var tickFontFamily = helpers.getValueOrDefault(xScale.options.ticks.fontFamily, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                    var tickLabelFont = helpers.fontString(tickFontSize, tickFontStyle, tickFontFamily);
                    var tl = xScale.options.gridLines.tickMarkLength;

                    var isRotated = xScale.labelRotation !== 0;
                    var yTickStart = xScale.top;
                    var yTickEnd = xScale.top + tl;
                    var chartArea = chart.chartArea;

                    // use the saved ticks
                    var maxTicks = xScale.options.ticks._maxTicksLimit - 1;
                    var ticksPerVisibleTick = xScale.ticks.length / maxTicks;

                    // chart.js uses an integral skipRatio - this causes all the fractional ticks to be accounted for between the last 2 labels
                    // we use a fractional skipRatio
                    var ticksCovered = 0;
                    helpers.each(xScale.ticks, function (label, index) {
                        if (index < ticksCovered)
                            return;

                        ticksCovered += ticksPerVisibleTick;

                        // chart.js has already drawn these 2
                        if (index === 0 || index === (xScale.ticks.length - 1))
                            return;

                        // copy of chart.js code
                        var xLineValue = this.getPixelForTick(index);
                        var xLabelValue = this.getPixelForTick(index, this.options.gridLines.offsetGridLines);

                        if (this.options.gridLines.display) {
                            this.ctx.lineWidth = this.options.gridLines.lineWidth;
                            this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.options.gridLines.color;

                            xLineValue += helpers.aliasPixel(this.ctx.lineWidth);

                            // Draw the label area
                            this.ctx.beginPath();

                            if (this.options.gridLines.drawTicks) {
                                this.ctx.moveTo(xLineValue, yTickStart);
                                this.ctx.lineTo(xLineValue, yTickEnd);
                            }

                            // Draw the chart area
                            if (this.options.gridLines.drawOnChartArea) {
                                this.ctx.moveTo(xLineValue, chartArea.top);
                                this.ctx.lineTo(xLineValue, chartArea.bottom);
                            }

                            // Need to stroke in the loop because we are potentially changing line widths & colours
                            this.ctx.stroke();
                        }

                        if (this.options.ticks.display) {
                            this.ctx.save();
                            this.ctx.translate(xLabelValue + this.options.ticks.labelOffset, (isRotated) ? this.top + 12 : this.options.position === "top" ? this.bottom - tl : this.top + tl);
                            this.ctx.rotate(helpers.toRadians(this.labelRotation) * -1);
                            this.ctx.font = tickLabelFont;
                            this.ctx.textAlign = (isRotated) ? "right" : "center";
                            this.ctx.textBaseline = (isRotated) ? "middle" : this.options.position === "top" ? "bottom" : "top";
                            this.ctx.fillText(label, 0, 0);
                            this.ctx.restore();
                        }
                    }, xScale);
                }
            };
        }
    },
});
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bh63pe1v/

Comment: wow, this works perfectly ! I think Chart.js should integrate your codes to make the `maxTicksLimit` work better.

Comment: after further testing, when the canvas becomes smaller, the ticks cannot be displayed properly **randomly** (only the first and the last ticks are shown); sometimes it shows properly after a refresh. See this: http://imgur.com/RtgYWZc

Comment: can you update the fiddle in my answer with your HTML and data? Does this display problem appear randomly for the same data or when data changes? any console error when the problem happens?

Comment: thanks for your reply. Here is an update with real data: http://jsfiddle.net/xk5d48yt/1/ . One thing to correct is, the effect is not randomly appearing. it is triggered when hovering the line. If you hover on the line, the unwanted effect will appear. No error in Developer Console.

Comment: thanks for finding that! I was changing the `maxTicksCount` to 2 - which actually caused it to take it as 2 the next time around (when a redraw is forced during tooltips update). Also, when tooltips are drawn the plugins are apparently not being notified. Worked around that by overriding the `scale.draw`. Give it a spin and let me know if I've broken anything else :-) Cheers!

Comment: Incredible ! it works perfectly now ! Really thanks for your help.

Comment: no problem! if you're dynamically updating the chart though, you might need to change it a bit (could be as easy as checking if _maxTicksLimit is already set)

Comment: Doesn't this seem a bit of overkill to locate the ticks evenly? I mean, shouldn't they upgrade their logic or something?

Comment: @DongBinKim - probably (unless they've already done so - it's been a while since I've looked at the code and there's been a number of releases since this answer). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Great job. But I tested last updated fiddle -> jsfiddle.net/xk5d48yt/1 with last version of Chart.js (2.7.2) looks like they must be changed something, so now it draws wrong. Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/xk5d48yt/6/

Answer (score 12):

A simpler solution until this is permanently fixed by the Chart JS contributors is to include a decimal in `maxTicksLimit`.

For example:

```
maxTicksLimit: 8,
```

produces a huge gap at the end.

```
maxTicksLimit: 8.1,
```

Does not produce a huge gap at the end.

Depending on what you want to set your maxTicksLimit to, you need to play around with different decimals to see which one produces the best result.

Comment: This is noteworthy. After 2 years, I wonder if they fixed this issue yet.

Comment: I'm using the latest version, and the issue is still present on both axes :(

Comment: Still a problem for me.  This solution works *most* of the time, but still occasionally has a wider gap for the last column.  I have a graph that the user can redraw to zoom in and out and on one of the views the last column will be too wide.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
        stepSize: Math.round((Math.max.apply(Math, myListOfyValues) / 10)/5)*5,
        beginAtZero: true,
        precision: 0
    }
}]
```

**10 = the number of ticks**

**5 = rounds tick values to the nearest 5 - all y values will be incremented evenly**

***Similar will work for xAxes too.***