# Chart.js draw mathematical function

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am creating an application where you can create a flow chart (diagram). then I am analyzing this algorithm and I am creating a chart with `Chart.js` where the x axis is a number of inputs/size of input and y axis is the number of steps the program took. I need to draw the following mathematical functions in the `Chart.js`:

```
f(x) = x, f(x) = x^2, f(x) = x*log(x).
```

Those are the complexities of algorithms I need to draw... I am using `typescript` by the way. Is it possible?

Comment: What's the difficulty? What have you tried?

Comment: @jcaron difficulty? I don't understand what you're asking? I haven't tried anything, I am asking if it's possible...

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? It's just a matter of computing the value of each of the functions for each value of x.

Comment: Sounds interesting... I will give it a try ...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using [Chart.js plugins](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-creating-plugins) can help you doing it quite easily. A plugin lets you handle some events triggered through the chart creation such as the initialization, the resize, etc.

```js
Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeInit: function(chart) {
        // All the code added here will be executed before the chart initialization
    }
});
```

---

I'll add a plugin which could be useful for your problem, but first let me explain how it works.

First, you'd need to add a new attribute to your datasets, named `function`. Its value must be a function with one argument and a returned value :

```
var data = {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    datasets: [{
        label: "f(x) = x", // Name it as you want
        function: function(x) { return x },
        data: [], // Don't forget to add an empty data array, or else it will break
        borderColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
        fill: false
    },
    {
        label: "f(x) = x²",
        function: function(x) { return x*x },
        data: [],
        borderColor: "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
        fill: false
    }]
}
```

Now you have to add the following plugin **before** you call `new Chart()` (*to create your chart*) or else it won't be added into the chart's plugin service :

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeInit: function(chart) {
        // We get the chart data
        var data = chart.config.data;

        // For every dataset ...
        for (var i = 0; i < data.datasets.length; i++) {

            // For every label ...
            for (var j = 0; j < data.labels.length; j++) {

                // We get the dataset's function and calculate the value
                var fct = data.datasets[i].function,
                    x = data.labels[j],
                    y = fct(x);
                // Then we add the value to the dataset data
                data.datasets[i].data.push(y);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You can now freely create your chart with the options you need.

---

Follows the result of a fully working example which you can find [on this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0hymmhc/) :

[image]

Comment: If you want more precision on X axis you may need this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250456/how-can-i-evenly-distribute-ticks-when-using-maxtickslimit/37257056#37257056