# Ticks for the minimum and maximum values in a Chart.js v2 axis

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

In Chart.js v2, how can one set up an axis so that it always shows ticks for the minimum and maximum values in a dataset?  That feature may be somewhere in the configuration options, but it's certainly not obvious.  I've even tried writing text to the canvas object using plugins, but something outside the available API hooks repaints the bitmap when I get new data.

Here's the latest configuration, which is returned by a function when the user navigates to a new time:

```
return {
    defaults: {
        global: {
            elements: {
                point: {
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    borderColor: 'transparent',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                }
            },
            line: {
                borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                lineTension: 0.1
            }
        }
    },
    type: 'line',
    responsive: true,
    data: {datasets: this.chartData},
    colors: [],
    labels: [],
    plugins: [
        // These are diagnostic checks for writing to canvas;
        // they fire and work on page load, but once data is loaded they vanish and never re-appear.
        // todo: find out what keeps resetting the chart's canvas tag AFTER the API hooks are done.
        {afterDraw: function (chart, options) {
            console.log('afterDraw');
            if (chart.chartArea === undefined) { return; }
            chart.ctx.fillText('afterDraw', chart.chartArea.left, chart.chartArea.bottom + 30);
        }}
        // Similar additions with the same job have been omitted; no sense in repeating them
    ],
    options: {
        animation: false,
        hover: {
            animationDuration: 0
        },
        responsiveAnimationDuration: 0,
        layout: {
            padding: {
                left: 10,
                right: 10,
                top: 10,
                bottom: 0
            }
        },
        legend: {
            display: false,
            position: 'bottom',
            labels: {
                boxWidth: 80,
                fontColor: 'black'
            }
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            ticks: {
                autoSkip: false,
                major: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                min: moment(TimeSpan.fromMidnightOf(this.timeSpan.startMs)),
                max: moment(TimeSpan.toMidnightOf(this.timeSpan.startMs)),
                source: 'data'
            },
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                    color: 'black'
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Time',
                    fontColor: 'black'
                },
                type: 'time',
                ticks: {
                    padding: -5,
                    suggestedMin: moment(TimeSpan.fromMidnightOf(this.timeSpan.startMs)),
                    suggestedMax: moment(TimeSpan.toMidnightOf(this.timeSpan.startMs))
                },
                time: {
                    displayFormats: {
                        // Overwriting the formats with a string value here
                        'hour': this.getFormatForTimeSpan(),
                        'day': this.getFormatForTimeSpan(),
                        'week': this.getFormatForTimeSpan(),
                        'month': this.getFormatForTimeSpan(),
                        'year': this.getFormatForTimeSpan(),
                    },
                    max: moment(TimeSpan.toMidnightOf(this.timeSpan.startMs)),
                    min: moment(TimeSpan.fromMidnightOf(this.timeSpan.startMs)),
                    unit: this.timeSpan.getTimeSpanUnit(),
                    unitStepSize: 1
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    color: 'black',
                    display: false
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Average Reading',
                    fontColor: 'black'
                },
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        },
        scaleShowValues: true,
        tooltips: {
            position: 'nearest',
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false,
        },
    }
};
```

If anyone can point out any flaws in the configuration, I'd love to hear what they have to say...

Comment: please update your question with examples of the code you have tried etc.

Comment: My attempt to write to the Canvas object turns out to mirror the approach in [Chart.js: evenly distribute ticks when using maxTicksLimit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250456/chart-js-evenly-distribute-ticks-when-using-maxtickslimit/37257056#37257056), but the result of that also gets wiped out when I load in data.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/

The default configuration for a scale can be easily changed using the scale service. All you need to do is to pass in a partial configuration that will be merged with the current scale default configuration to form the new default.

For example, to set the minimum value of 0 for all linear scales, you would do the following. Any linear scales created after this time would now have a minimum of 0.

Chart.scaleService.updateScaleDefaults('linear', {

```
ticks: {

    min: 0

}
```

});