# Line chart with equal column widths

Tags: chart.js

I created a line chart with chart.js and when I populate it, the last column is wider than the previous columns.  It has divided the dataset by the number of display columns and put the remainder into the final column.  The number of data points varies and is greater than the number of columns and I have no idea either how many data points there will be or how many columns chart.js will chose to display.  I can truncate the data in order to force the last column to match, but I don't know how many columns it's going to create before it renders the graph.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Update:

```
var options = {
    layout: {
        padding: {
            top: 5
        }
    },
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom',
        // disable legend onclick remove slice
        onClick: null
    }
};

var dataset = new Object();
dataset = [{
    label: '',
    data: [],
    fill: false,
    borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
    pointBackgroundColor: '#000000',
    pointRadius: 1
}, {
    label: 'Set Point',
    data: [],
    fill: false,
    borderColor: "rgb(192, 192, 75)",
    pointRadius: 1
}];

var lineChart = new Chart(graph, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: dataset
    },
    options: options
});
lineChart.config.data.datasets[0].label = sensor.Name;

for (var i = 0; i < tempLen; i++) {
    var tempData = sensor.TemperatureData[i];
    lineChart.config.data.labels.push(new Date(tempData.Timestamp).format('Y-m-#d #H:i'));
    lineChart.config.data.datasets[0].data.push(tempData.Value);
    lineChart.config.data.datasets[1].data.push(sensor.SetPoint);
}
lineChart.update(0);
```

Comment: Can you publish some code/data so we can see the issue?

Comment: I'll update the question with my setup, but the data sets are large and I can't really post them.  I can provide a link to a site where the problem is exhibited, but that usually runs afoul of: Don't just post a link, post the actual data here in case the link goes stale.

Comment: Turns out this is a duplicate.  Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250456/chart-js-evenly-distribute-ticks-when-using-maxtickslimit