# Vertical Gird Line Issue with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using the [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) library to create a line graph and due to the high number of labels needed I've skipped some using the method in the  [Limit labels number on Chartjs line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22064577/limit-labels-number-on-chartjs-line-chart) question, also see below.

My chart looks exactly how I want it to with one exception:
[image]
There is a random black line appearing where the second label would normal be.

This is the code I've used to create this chart:

```js
Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.radius = 2;

var ctx = document.getElementById("graph-1-met");

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [0,'','','','','',1,'','','','','',2,'','','','','',3,'','','','','',4,'','','','','',5,'','','','','',6,'','','','','',7,'','','','','',8,'','','','','',9,'','','','','',10,'','','','','',11,'','','','','',12,'','','','','',13,'','','','','',14,'','','','','',15,'','','','',''],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55],
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0,204,255,0.2)",
                borderColor: "rgba(0,204,255,1)",
                borderWidth: 2
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Blowing Time (min)'
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Undissolved Lime (tonnes)'
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="graph-1-met"></canvas>
```

I'd like to note a few things:

- If I use an actual label (e.g. `[0,1,2,3,4,...]`) the black line *does not* appear. Which leads me to believe something is going wrong with my use of empty strings (`''`).
- When I change the label to: `[0,1,'','',...]` the black line now appears on the first occurrence of `''`. In this case the 3rd label position.
- In an attempt to fix the problem I tried setting the colour of the gridlines to white and this caused black line to no longer appeared. Unfortunately, this solution makes the graph look substantially worse.

**Question: Why is this black line appearing and is there a way to remove it?**

Comment: When you inspect the line (with dev tools) does it give any indication what's causing it? A class name, `data-*`, id, etc.?

Comment: @adam-beck, it's a canvas element

Comment: @adam-beck As Mi-Creativity said, the entire element is a canvas. Unfortunately, the Chart.js library builds the entire graph within the single element, so inspecting doesn't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this might be weird, but I just removed every **`''`** from the `labels` array and it renders like it should.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjy3Lee4/)**

```js
Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.radius = 2;

var ctx = document.getElementById("graph-1-met");

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [0, , , , , 1, , , , , , 2, , , , , , 3, , , , , , 4, , , , , , 5, , , , , , 6, , , , , , 7, , , , , , 8, , , , , , 9, , , , , , 10, , , , , , 11, , , , , , 12, , , , , , 13, , , , , , 14, , , , , , 15, , , , , ],
    datasets: [{
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,204,255,0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(0,204,255,1)",
      borderWidth: 2,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Blowing Time (min)'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Undissolved Lime (tonnes)'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="graph-1-met"></canvas>
```