# Showing every other label on yAxis canvas chartjs

Tags: canvas, charts, ng2-charts

I wanted to know is there a way that I can control how many labels get to be displayed - I know there is the `stepSize` feature but that is numerical. I am looking for something like `interval:3` so it will show every third label on the graph.

```
options: {
  scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero:true,
          max: 100
        }
      }],
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
          }
        }]
    }
}
```

This is how i am rendering my chart:

html:

```
<div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:20vh; width:40vw">
      <canvas id="chartGraph"   baseChart [colors]="colorsOverride" [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="false" [chartType]="barChartType">
      </canvas>
</div>
```

in my component.ts i have:

```
barChartOptions: any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero:true,
          max: 100
        }
      }],
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {

          }
        }]
    },
      tooltips:{
        mode: 'point'
      }
  };
  barChartLabels: string[] = [];
  barChartType: string = 'horizontalBar';
  barChartLegend: boolean = false;
  barChartData: any[] = [];
  data: any;

  colorsOverride: Array<Color> = [{
    backgroundColor: '#6aaf6a',
    hoverBackgroundColor: 'purple'
  }];

    getChartData(link:string){
        this.service.getQuery(link).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.data = data;
                this.barChartLabels = this.data.map(x => x.display);
                this.chartData = this.data.map(x => x.value);
                this.barChartData = [{data: this.chartData, label:'sample' }];
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: @ℊααnd this is more of a numeric interval but i am looking for label interval so like it shows the labels of January, March, May.... yet the bar graphs will show for each month. (based on your example)

Comment: @ℊααnd yes - what property did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Source: [Limit labels number on Chart.js line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22064577/limit-labels-number-on-chart-js-line-chart#answer-38973477)

The example provided by [George](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1354119/george-d) blanks every other label.

```
 var options =  {  
     scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            afterTickToLabelConversion: function(data){

                var xLabels = data.ticks;

                xLabels.forEach(function (labels, i) {
                    if (i % 2 == 1){
                        xLabels[i] = '';
                    }
                });
            } 
        }]   
    }
}
```

To retain the first value in the X axes, and then the fourth, eighth, and so on, you could change the if statement to:

```
if (i % 4 != 0){ 
    xLabels[i] = ''; 
}
```

The solution works well for yAxes options as well. The variable name xLabels is not a part of chartjs and no harm will come from altering it.