# How to make ticks distance fixed in a logarithmic line chart

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I'm using chart.js for a project and I want to make distance between ticks fixed

I tried to read the docs but didn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: Isn’t that related to the data on the chart?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39326127/19117205). It doesn't exactly let you set the distance, but you can limit how many ticks there are which may give you the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks, but that option doesn't make the space fixed, just reduces the ticks.